# Adding drag & drop on UIView on long press in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, drag-and-drop

I am have a `UIView` on which i want to Implement Drag & Drop feature.I have tried using Pan gesture in that case i am able to drag the view on screen but i am not able to get that drag & drop effect.My requiremnts are.

- Show view as selected on long press & move view only after long press.
- Create a shadow effect for dragging & dropping.
- Highlight the destination few on which i want to drop the view.

I have tried exploring using [this](http://Oblong/OBDragDrop%20%C2%B7%20GitHub) but i am not able to use it.
Please suggesst me some more ways of doing it.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/frenetisch-applaudierend/ios-drag-and-drop

Comment: This only works for UIview but not for any other view